# how to setting multi monitor on ocx.UseMultimon = true;

Tags: c#

I create rdp with c# using the library `AxMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting`, it's running ok. However, if I use 2 monitors it's just show one monitor.

I tried using:

```cs
ocx.UseMultimon = true;
```

but this did not work.

Comment: Note the usage of FullScreen: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2014/12/31/using-multiple-monitors-programmatically-from-an-rdp-active-x-control/

Comment: i'am ready use 
UseMultimon = true;
 but not working